# Test useFormik hook with React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

I did a thorough search before positing this question, most of them were using `<Formik/>` where they had sent `onSubmit` handler as a prop so that it can be tested whether it is called or not when the form is submitted.

In my case, I'm using `useFormik` hook for my form and I can't get to reach the `onSubmit` code when the form is submitted. The type property of button is `submit` so the `onClick` function is `undefined` when I displayed the element in console log.

Below is excerpt from my code

**Component**

```
export const WithMaterialUI = () => {
  const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      email: "foobar@example.com"
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
    onSubmit: (values) => {
      alert(JSON.stringify(values, null, 2));
    }
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} data-testid="form">
        <TextField
          data-testid="email"
          fullWidth
          id="email"
          name="email"
          label="Email"
          value={formik.values.email}
          onChange={formik.handleChange}
          error={formik.touched.email && Boolean(formik.errors.email)}
          helperText={formik.touched.email && formik.errors.email}
        />
        <Button color="primary" variant="contained" fullWidth type="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};
```

**Test case**

```
const mockSubmit = jest.fn();

describe("Test for formik onSubmit", () => {
  it("should handle form submission", async () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<WithMaterialUI />);

    const email = getByTestId("email");
    const form = getByTestId("form");

    act(() => {
      fireEvent.change(email, { target: { value: "abc@gmail.com" } });
    });

    act(() => {
      fireEvent.submit(form);
    });

    await waitFor(() => {
      expect(mockSubmit).toHaveBeenCalled();
    });
  });
});
```

I created a working example using [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/formik-test-case-w5iu7?file=/index.js:551-565). Could anyone please help?

Comment: May I suggest you use: https://testing-library.com/

you basically just really should test what a user would do, menaing using react testing library read the field, fill it and click submit. You can find examples online: https://testing-library.com/docs/example-codesandbox

Comment: Agree with above. When you press "Submit" try changing the button text to "Submitting...". This way you can write a test where you simulate that button click, like a real user and then check that the button text changed to "Submitting...", like a real user.

Comment: I think this is a valid use case of using react testing library simulating the user behavior, as it's also in the examples (https://testing-library.com/docs/example-react-formik).

Comment: Did you manage to see, if your fireEvent update your input ? 
Im facing almost the same issue, impossible to trigger an handleChange event

Answer (score 1):

You should use `jest.mock`:

```
const setFieldValue = jest.fn();
const handleSubmit = jest.fn();
jest.mock('formik', () => ({
  useFormik: () => ({
    setFieldValue,
    handleSubmit,
    values: {
      transferMethodCountry: 'AZ',
      transferMethodCurrency: 'AZN',
      type: 'BANK_ACCOUNT',
    },
  }),
}));
```

and `except(handleSubmit).toBeCalled()`

Comment: Do you know how to use also  original e.g. setFieldValue implementation and  mocked handleSubmit?