# How to write test when passing Formik state as a props?

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library, formik

I have two components, ComponentA pass formikBag to ComponentB. I use React-testing library to write test for ComponentB. But when running the test, it shows **Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.** The formikBag contains lots of values, such as values, onSubmit, onBlur..etc.

```
const ComponentA = () => {
  const formikBag = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: "xxx", id: 1
    },
  });

  return <ComponentB formikBag={formikBag} />
}
```

```
const ComponentB = ({formikBag}) => {
  const { values, setFieldValue, setValues } = formikBag;
  return <div>{values.name}</div>
}
```

```
// ComponentB testing

test('should render <Ctable />', async () => {
  const formikBag = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
      name: "xxx", id: 1
    },
  });
  const { asFragment } = render(
      <ThemeProvider>
        <MockedProvider mocks={[mockQueryMe]}>
          <ComponentB formikBag={formikBag} />
        </MockedProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
  );
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

I check the possible solution on [Test useFormik hook with React Testing Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036941/test-useformik-hook-with-react-testing-library). But it is not similar as my case. How do I define it as a props?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is exactly right: you're calling a hook outside of a component render. The solution is to wrap the hook call in a component that you render:

```
test('should render <Ctable />', async () => {
  const TestComponent = () => {
    const formikBag = useFormik({
      initialValues: {
        name: "xxx", id: 1
      },
    });
    return <ComponentB formikBag={formikBag} />;
  };
  const { asFragment } = render(
      <ThemeProvider>
        <MockedProvider mocks={[mockQueryMe]}>
          <TestComponent />
        </MockedProvider>
      </ThemeProvider>
  );
  await waitFor(() => {
    expect(asFragment()).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```